# Many questions about the various C++ compilers available to me on OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, gcc

I am having trouble understanding the different compilers that are available to me.

I mainly use Xcode for writing and compiling, and in Xcode's preferences, there are all of these options for C++ compilation:

C++ Language Dialect:

- C++98[-std=c++98] through C++14[-std=c++14]
- GNU++98[-std=gnu++98] through GNU++14[-std=gnu++14]

C++ Standard Library:

- libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
- libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

  1. Can someone explain what exactly all of that ^ is?
  2. I understand that (and correct me if I'm wrong), that apple no longer distributes GCC with Xcode and use Clang instead?
  3. If that were the case, then why does Xcode have the option for GNU C++ standard library? Doesn't GNU make GCC?
  4. What compiler is invoked when I run C++ code in my local terminal with `g++ filename.cpp`?
  5. Is there any way to make sure that this `g++` "compiler" is up to date?
  6. What's the difference between compiling with `g++` in the terminal and using Xcode?
  7. Also, what would be the difference if I tried running C++ programs with Clang?
  8. My class requires us to test our programs on the department's server's compiler via ssh from my terminal. The server is a Unix machine and I know that its compiler is GNU's GCC compiler and we also access it using `g++`. Does this mean that the local `g++` in my terminal is also GCC?

edit: Grammar

Comment: check out homebrew's gcc

Comment: if you are want to get information about what kind of `gcc` you have, go to your terminal and type `gcc -v`. On apple machines, by default, they make a symlink of apple clang `darwin` called `gcc`, so most likely `gcc -v` and `clang -v` will look the same to you, unless you installed a real gcc somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

C++ language dialect

```
C++98[-std=c++98] through C++14[-std=c++14]
GNU++98[-std=gnu++98] through GNU++14[-std=gnu++14]
```

The C++ language has evolved over time. These are the various versions of the language that are available to you. If you have to be compatible with something old, you might be forced to use an old one. Otherwise you'd probably want ot use the newest available, which is c++14 in the list above. 14 stands for 2014, 98 for 1998 - it is supposed to represent the year that version of the standard was blessed.

In addition to standard C++ there are non-standard extensions. Gnu is a compiler "manufacturer", the "GNU" above is the non-stanadard extensions as specified by GNU for a particular documented version.

C++ Standard Library:

libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

In addition to the base language, the standard library is also a part of the standard. These are two different implementations of the standard library. The first is by GNU, the second by llvm. llvm are a different compiler manufacturer.

On osx you'd probably use libc++ as I believe the llvm compiler (clang++) is now standard there. The llvm compiler will support the gnu extensions if you need them. You probably don't. Just use the latest version of whatever is default.

2. Yes
3. two different pieces, the compiler and the standard library. You can use clang++ with libstd++
4. g++ -v will tell you
5. not really. Update xcode to the newest or start looking at homebrew or ports to get the latest and greatest they package of whatever compiler you like.
6. Probably the same compiler, you can set it either to point at any compiler you have installed. So what each points at is your choice.
7. both g++ and clang++ are standards compliant. You're unlikely to notice much difference. They will complile the same source files into equivalent binaries.
8. run g++ -v in any terminal to see exactly what it is.